# iOS 12/Swift Strong Password AutoFill doesn't work as expected

Tags: swift, autofill, ios12

I have set on `UITextFields`

- `emailTextField` -> username, `keyboardType` email address
- `passwordTextField` -> new password
- `confirmPasswordTextField` -> new password

This form doesn't work as expected 
I have no username suggestion, only if the user is connected with a domain in keychain there is like login suggestion

`passwordTextField` is filled with strong password but not confirm password. 
Moreover when I choose `confirmPasswordTextField` then new password is generated for both fields. If I select Own Password then type `passwordTextField` and try to retype it in `confirmPasswordTextField` it is suggested again now filling both `UITextFields`.

It seems to be very messy and stupid, making it hard for the user to properly choose own password or strong password. How to make it work correctly.

The most frustrating thing is that when I select Choose Own Password, text fields are cleared correctly, but once I start typing into my first `UITextField` then second confirm field is filled with this strong password but without yellow background.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had a similar problem, and solved it by setting the type of `passwordTextField` to `.password` and the type of `confirmPasswordTextField` to `.newPassword`.

Answer (score 1):

For me It works if I use `.password` **in both fields**. Using `.newPassword` adds some messy things.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with not correctly filled password field. I had to uncheck the "Clear when editing begins" box to get it working (located in Attributes Inspector from the textField).